# Can I use diodes to protect power supply outputs?

Tags: power-supply, dc, power-electronics, pulse, low-voltage

(Note, this is my first question on this site, please point out if there is something that I am doing wrong here.)

I have a thyratron that requires two separate power lines to attach to it. The two power lines meet at a single terminal on the thyratron tube.

One of the lines is a -100 volt DC and 100 milli-amp bias.

The other line is a series of 200 V pulses that are sent out at a frequency of 10 hertz. The pulses last for 0.4 micro seconds and have a rise and fall time of 1.5 kV/uS (the 200 V needs to be reached in 7.5 uS or less). Please also note that the pulses are only positive, so there are just 10 of these every second.

Since the pulses would probably mess up the DC bias, it seems reasonable that I would put a capacitor between the terminal and the pulse source and an inductor between the DC source and the terminal.

My question is, how should I calculate the capacitance and inductance that will be needed?

Also, could I just use a diode to protect the DC and pulse source?

Here is link to the basics of a thyratron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyratron

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQa46Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the advice, just put it in. Its a really cool feature, I think I'll use that for my own designing!

Comment: Good work, but it doesn't clear up much. Where's the thyristor? (CircuitLab has one at the bottom of the component library.) When you say "thyristor tube" what exactly do you mean? (It sounds like something made of glass.) Have you got a part number and a link? What is the circuit supposed to do?

Comment: @Transistor I got two things confused, I should have said "Thyratron," not thyristor. The node labeled "terminal" in the diagram is found on the thyratron. It is a CX-1538 R made by English Electronics. One of the things that the thyratron needs is the bias voltage and the trigger pulse voltage to be applied to the same place. I don't have a detailed diagram of the thyratron.

Comment: Hit the edit link again to correct the thyristor error ... Add in a link to a good introductory text to educate those of us (including me) that have never heard of a thyratron. The 100 mA source may be OK. What's the source impedance of the square wave?

Comment: Edits added; but I don't know if that is so much the point. For a second, imagine that the power was going to a resistor and would then be grounded (this is sort of like what is happening here). Use that perspective for the question.

Comment: Also, the impedance of the square wave is 50 ohms. What equations would I need to make find the results?

Comment: I don't know. Without knowing the circuitry of the 100 V PSU it's hard to know whether a 200 V backfed pulse would upset it or not. The impedance of a capacitor is given by \$ Z = \frac {1}{2 \pi f C} \$ so try going as low as you want there (50 \$ \Omega \$?). I presume that the 200 V source will be able to take the 100 V transient when the DC supply is switched on. I'm probably at the end of being any further use to you.

Comment: @transistor Thank you for your responses. I have yet to find a power supply, however, I am making the assumption that it cannot handle any sort of pulse going into it. Would a diode work to stop the pulses from going in?

Comment: It would on its own but not with a capacitor as it would prevent the capacitor discharging when the AC goes low. Have fun.

Comment: @JamesLi - "*I have a thyristor that requires two separate power lines to attach to it. The two power lines meet at a single terminal on the thyristor tube*" Do you really mean that? From the earlier comments, it seems you might have meant to say "thyratron tube" in every place where you said "thyristor". Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I meant to say thyratron back there, there turned out to be no thyristor. In reality, there is a terminal on the thyratron where the two wires need to lead to. This terminal is where the thyratron is instructed to provide a certain pulse frequency.

Comment: @JamesLi - "*I meant to say thyratron back there*" Thanks for the reply. In that case, please click "edit" under your question and correct the text wherever needed (I see that you have edited the question already, so you know how to do that). You can't expect readers to read all the comments, to find out that you already know some parts of the question are actually incorrect! Thanks :-)

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for pointing that out, I'm hoping that explains a lot of the confusion. As for the question, would I be able to use a simple diode or should I use a capacitor and inductor?